# How to make more jagged terrain

Tags: procedural-generation, terrain, minecraft-modding

I need some help with some terrain I'm working on. I'm developing a plugin for Minecraft, but these concepts will apply to any game with terrain. I am using Simplex noise to generate cavern-like terrain. I am using the power of the noise to generate hills that look like this:

[image]

As you can probably tell, it inst looking very cavern-like. What can I do to improve this terrain?

Comment: Lynda.Com has a unity course by Michael house with a couple of lessons on procedural terrain generation that might help, although you would have to pay their monthly fee - about $25-$30

Comment: How are you generating your noise?

Comment: @Pikalek Im using Simplex noise

Comment: That doesn't give us much info. How are you generating it? What parameters are you using?

Comment: Without defining what you mean by "improve" this is probably too unclear to answer effectively without just guessing. Do you want it smoother? More variety? More natural or cave-like? Less natural or cave-like?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to make it more jagged is to add noise to it. You'll get various spikes at various points.

Another thing you could do is take your values and apply some function to them. For example, if your heights are between 0 and 1 when generating your height map, you can square them. That will result in the slopes being more extreme throughout the map.

Comment: There's also the option of downscaling the algorithm and projecting it again on the larger scale algorithm to get a bumpier cave without requiring more mathematical leaps.